# Which present tense should you use when talking about continuous pain?

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense, present-continuous

The speaker can still feel the pain in the moment of speaking (he's asking if he's still able to go abroad with this back pain) & it's some sort of dialogue between some ordinary guy & a doctor.

Which present tense should you use when talking about continuous pain?

> 1. I am having a pain for two days.
> 2. I've been having a pain for two days.
> 3. I've had a pain for two days.

Comment: I've got it for two days...? I have got a stomachache for two days? Not quite sure, though...

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with #2 present perfect continuous, but typical usage would suggest that you would say "I have been having pain" not "having **a** pain".

Or consider using "experiencing" instead of *having* which may be a stronger verb for this case:

> "I have been *experiencing* pain..."

but present perfect continuous (use of "been") is my thinking.

Answer (score 1):

1. **I am having a pain for two days*.

This is totally unacceptable.

2. **I've been having a pain for two days*.

Also unacceptable in this sense. However,

2'. *I've been having pain [in my back] for two days.*

is acceptable and (especially with the 'padding') idiomatic. Note that

2''. *I've been having a pain on and off for two days.*

is acceptable, idiomatic, but indicates an iterative, not continuous, sensation.

3. *I've had a pain for two days.*

is acceptable and totally idiomatic.

3'. *I've had pain for two days.*

sounds ultra-formal and quite old-fashioned.